# createDialog for onBackPressed but my app showing error close app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created a new layout name dialog_exit for onBackPressed but when I install and open, my application can not open and showing error close app 
Please review my whole code and guide me how can I solve this problem 
Here is my  main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Dialog mDialog;
    public Button mDialogyes, mDialogno;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createDialog();
    }

    private void createDialog() {
        mDialog = new Dialog(this);
        mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_exit);
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialogyes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yes);
        mDialogno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.no);

        mDialogyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);

                mDialogno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Here is my layout code as screenshot because

[stackoverflow not allow me to add more code that why sharing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCLf.png)

Comment: which err is occurred ? put Err Log here

Comment: Please paste your layout code as well?

Comment: Not sure what issue you are trying to fix, but your no buttons click listener is setup inside your yes click listener. This will effectively make your no button button useless. Move this outside of the on click method of your yes buttpn.

Comment: Please check my layout code from screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVCLf.png

Comment: Please also add the error logs to your question as Hardik Vasani already mentioned. They are more important.

Comment: Its showing error that app has stopped open app again

Comment: @Ayan Ok, But what is the stacktrace from the logcat console (In Android studio on the bottom) when the app crashes?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated code of createDialog function**

```
 private void createDialog() {
    mDialog = new Dialog(this);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_exit);
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialogyes = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    mDialogno = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

    mDialogyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }

    });

    mDialogno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: one more problem that Yes button working fine and exit the app but when i click on No button then nothing do anything can you help

Comment: See the comment from Joel Libby. Move "mDialogno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()..." outside of the click listener of the yes button.

Comment: I update the code again use this updated code.Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hello once again need small help

Comment: Hello once again need small help that am showing admob ads in my alert dialog layout but its not showing.                             



 adView = (AdView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.adView);

      AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code 
       mDialogyes = (Button)mDialogyes. findViewById(R.id.yes);
        mDialogno = (Button)mDialogyes. findViewById(R.id.no);

    mDialogyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);


            }

        });

           mDialogno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: after mDialog.setCancelable(true); line

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

```
mDialogyes = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
mDialogno = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
```